# newman run -k <collection> -e <environment> is not running and it is throwing error

Tags: node.js, npm, postman, newman

`newman run -k <collection> -e <environment>` is not running and it is throwing error like below,

> "unable to read data from file "-k" ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open 'D:\Development_Avecto\APIRegressionAuto
>   mation\EnvironmentsAndCollections-k' "

[image]

can someone help on this please?

Note :

```
node version - v4.1.2
npm version - 2.15.12
newman version - 3.9.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md) - You do not require the `-k` flag for the collection reference.

What newman is doing is looking for the first argument on the command line which it knows should be the `collection file` but it's finding `-k` instead and thinking that's the collection. So you get *"unable to read data from file "-k""*.

You can just write:

`newman run <collection> -e <environment>`

`-k` is the alias for insecure and if you want this it needs to be added after  the other flags.

`newman run <collection> -e <environment> -k`

Comment: I have to use "-k" as needs to disable ssl when running my collection. as you said, i have used -k after the other flags and its working now. thanks for your help :)